Could someone provide an analytical proof of empirically found formula?
$$a(n) = 2^{n/2 - 2} \times [(2 \sqrt 2 - 3) \times (-1)^{n + 1} + 3 + 2 
\sqrt 2)] + 2$$
Above empirically found concurrent formula matches OEIS sequence A209722, This sequence counts a specific arrangement of arrays and begins with the terms:
$$4,5,6,8,10,14,18,26,34$$
Could someone provide an analytical proof whether this empirically found formula corresponds to the definition of the OEIS sequence A209722?
PS The question of whether an empirically found formula corresponds to the definition of the OEIS sequence A209722 is relevant to the Math Stack Exchange community for several reasons:
Background and Motivation
Understanding the connection between empirical observations and formal mathematical definitions is fundamental in mathematics. A209722 is defined as the number of distinct arrangements in a specific kind of array, which invites inquiry into its mathematical properties. Verifying if a proposed formula accurately describes a sequence is critical for both theoretical exploration and practical applications in combinatorics and related fields.
Relevant Definitions

OEIS (On-Line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences): A comprehensive database of integer sequences where each sequence has a unique identifier (e.g., A209722) and often includes definitions, properties, and mathematical relationships.
Combinatorial Arrays: The context of A209722 involves specific arrangements of elements in multi-dimensional arrays, where properties like edge differences dictate the counting of arrangements.

Source
A209722 is maintained by the OEIS Foundation and is part of their extensive database, which provides details on sequences, including their mathematical properties, formulas, and connections to other sequences. For more details on the sequence, visit OEIS A209722.
Possible Strategies

Direct Computation: One approach is to compute the first few terms using both the empirical formula and the OEIS definition to see if they match.
Inductive Proof: Establish a base case and then use mathematical induction to show that the formula holds for all ( n ).
Combinatorial Interpretation: Develop a combinatorial argument that shows why the formula makes sense within the context of counting arrangements described by the OEIS sequence.

Importance
This question is intriguing because it highlights the relationship between empirical findings and formal proofs, a core aspect of mathematical investigation. It underscores the importance of validation in mathematics—showing that a conjectured formula indeed describes a sequence helps ensure the integrity of mathematical knowledge. Such inquiries can lead to deeper insights not only into the specific sequence in question but also into broader combinatorial principles.

OEIS entries begin with $a(0)$, so your formula is off by one. Swap $n$ and $n+1$ to correct this.

This scores highly on AI detectors.  The use of AI is frowned upon here.

Yes, this formula does match the given sequence. I can give an overview of the proof, and develop specific parts further as necessary.
Step 1: $2\times 2$ subblocks
The given sequence counts arrays in base 3 where every $2\times 2$ subblock has distinct clockwise edge differences. There are 5 possible differences in ternary, $-2,-1,0,1,2$. The four that show up as differences in our subblock must clearly sum to zero, which means it must omit $0$ as a difference (omitting any other of the five possibilities leaves $4$ numbers that do not sum to zero). Therefore, the edge differences are $-2,-1,1,2$, which in clock-wise order must have alternating sign to stay within the digits $0,1,2$. There are only 2 possibilities for such a cycle, the first being $2\to -1 \to 1 \to -2 $ and the second $2\to -2 \to 1 \to -1$ leading to the matrices
$$ M^1 = \left(\begin{matrix} 0 & 2 \\ 2 & 1 \end{matrix}\right), N^1= \left(\begin{matrix} 0 & 2 \\ 1 & 0 \end{matrix}\right) $$
and their rotations which I will denote by $M^i, N^i$ for $i = 1, 2, 3, 4$. Thus there are $8$ distinct possibilities for any $2\times 2$ subblock in the array. Note that, for both the $M^i$ and $N^i$ matrices, the $\pm 2$ difference edges correspond to rows/columns with $0$ and $2$ (which they must) but the $\pm 1$ difference edges differ between the two; in the $M^i$ they are rows/columns with $1$ and $2$, and in the $N^i$ they are rows/columns with $0$ and $1$. I will call these edges (1)-edges and (2)-edges, and note that (1)-edges are always opposite to (2)-edges in a subblock.
Step 2: Base Case
The case $n = 1$ corresponds to $4\times 2$ arrays, which can be thought of as two compatible subblocks placed on top of each other. I claim that for any choice of top subblock, there are exactly 2 compatible bottom subblocks, one $M^i$ one and one $N^i$ one. To prove this, let's call the top subblock $T$. If the bottom of $T$ is a (1)-edge $e$, then there is exactly one subblock $C$ that has $e$ as its top edge (since (1)-edges are distinct between type $M$s and type $N$s) which determines the 3rd row of the matrix. Then this row must be a (2)-edge, and so there are two distinct possibilities for the bottom subblock $B$ depending on if one chooses the $M$ version or the $N$ version. Alternatively, if the bottom edge of $T$ is a (2)-edge, then there are two possibilities for a center subblock $C$, each of which uniquely determine a bottom subblock $B$ from $C$'s bottom (1)-edge. Since there are 8 possibilities for $T$, we get 16 possible arrays for $n = 1$ (which becomes 4 after dividing by 4).
It is not hard to see that if $T$ and $B$ are the same subblock type, then they must actually be the same (i.e. if $T = M^i$ and $B = M^j$, then actually $i = j$) since this gives a valid array and the above construction is unique.
Step 3: Induction
For any $4\times(n+1)$ array, let $T$ be the upper right-most subblock and $B$ be the bottom right-most subblock. We start by defining a number of useful sequences; $a(n)$ is the number of total valid $4\times(n+1)$ arrays and what we seek to calculate. $b(n)$ will be the number of valid arrays where $T = B$ and their right edge is a (1)-edge, $c(n)$ will be the number of valid arrays where $T = B$ and their right edge is a (2)-edge, and $d(n)$ will be the number of valid arrays where $T$ and $B$ are disparate subblock times, one $M$ and one $N$. Clearly $a(n) = b(n) + c(n) + d(n)$, and we have found in the previous step that $b(1) = c(1) = 1, d(1) = 2$.
The key insight is the following recursive formula: $b(n) = 2c(n-1), c(n) = b(n-1)$, and $d(n) = d(n-1)$. Indeed, if we have a $4\times n$ array where $T = B$, and the right-most edges are (1)-edges, then there is exactly one way to extend this to a $4\times(n+1)$ array, which will have the property that $T' = B'$ with right-most edges being (2)-edges. This gives $c(n) = b(n-1)$. If we have a $4\times n$ array where $T = B$ and the right-most edges are (2)-edges, then there are exactly two ways to extend this to a $4\times(n+1)$ array, which will have the property that $T' = B'$ (one with the same and one with the opposite subtype to $T$ and $B$) with right-most edges being (1)-edges. This gives $b(n) = 2c(n-1)$. Finally, when $T$ and $B$ are opposite subtypes, one can show that one of their right-most edges will be a (1)-edge, which uniquely specifies 2 entries in the right-most column. However, then 3 entries of the new center array are specified which uniquely determines a 3rd  entry in the last column, which then determines the final entry. One can also show that the resulting array has $T'$ and $B'$ being opposite subblock types. Thus $d(n) = d(n-1)$.
Step 3: Counting
From the recursive definitions, one can derive that $b(n) = 2b(n-2)$ with $b(1) = 1, b(2) = 2$, $c(n) = 2c(n-2)$ with $c(1) = 1, c(2) = 1$, and $d(n) = d(n-1)$ with $d(1) = 2$. Solving this gives $d(n) = 2$ for all $n$,
$$b(n) = 2^{n/2-2}\times\left[(\sqrt{2} - 2)\times(-1)^{n+1} + 2 + \sqrt{2}\right],$$
and
$$c(n) = 2^{n/2-2}\times\left[(\sqrt{2} - 1)\times(-1)^{n+1} + 1 + \sqrt{2}\right].$$
Summing the three expressions yields the one you wrote. The empirical formula, generating functions, and explicit formulas for $a(n)$ in the case $n$ is even or odd on the OEIS site are all also true and follow similarly from the recursive formulas.
